# second grade move

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say we have a class that embed another parametric one, that has to support both copy and move.
And let's assume that -in certain circumstance- there is the need to get out the inner value somehow.

A typical approach can be this one:

```
template<class T>
class wrapper
{
public:
    wrapper() :val() {}
    wrapper(T s) :val(std::move(s)) {}

    wrapper(const wrapper& s) :val(s.val) {}
    wrapper(wrapper&& s) :val(std::move(s.val)) {}
    wrapper& operator=(wrapper s) { val = std::move(s.val); return *this; }

    T value() const { return val; }
private:
    T val;
};
```

That's not the only way of doing it, and may be there is no need to expliciate copy and move, but let them be.

The point is another: **Suppose `T` -in ceratin instances- is itself a copy/movable class**.
Of course, `wrapper::value()` returns a copy of T.

Now suppose the returned T has to go as a parameter into another call, and that the containing wrapper 
is temporary.

The simpler simulation is

```
calledfn(wrapper<T>(someT).value());
```

Again: done in this way is clueless, but more complex cases require this trivial one to work.

In theory we can admit to move away `val` from its temporary wrapper to give it to the caller, but...
what signature should have the `value()` method so that it is bound when `wrapper<T>` is temporary but is not bound when it is not temporary, for which `value() const` should be preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11 you can overload methods on wether or not the `this`-pointer is a rvalue:

```
T value() &&; //Will only be called if the object is a mutable rvalue
T value() const &; //Will only be called if the object is an lvalue
```

Note that according to  `13.1.2  [over.load]`in the standard if any overload has a reference specifier (lvalue or rvalue) all have to get one. So The overload for the non-temporary case has to be `const &`. I'm not completely sure wether or not this will bind  to a const r-value, so you might need a `const &&` overload to catch that case.

I don't know about the compiler support for this feature, so this might be somewhat theoretical if the support isn't there yet. In that case you might work around by creating a `move_value` method and using a free function which dispatches to the correct method:

```
template<class T> class wrapper {
    ...    
    T value() const;
    T move_value();    
};
template<typename T> T value(wrapper<T>&& self) { return std::move(self.move_value(); }
template<typename T> T value(const wrapper<T>& self) { return std::move(self.value(); }
```

Comment: Unfortunately the compiler complain about the `&&` before the `;` (gcc 4.7.0).

The workaround works perfectly. I just have to work it out much more to make it not `wrapper`-specific. Anyway thanks a lot!